# Change XrandR setup on monitor unplugged/replugged

Tags: arch-linux, external-display, acpi

I'm specifically looking for a way to set up my laptop, when I unplug the external display, to reset the XrandR configuration so I'm only using 1 screen. Any advice?

Basically, I want an acpi event on display disconnect. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write an udev rule for your external displays which will trigger your script doing the changes. More explanation on [this unix SE question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4489/a-tool-for-automatically-applying-randr-configuration-when-external-display-is-p) and [this blog post](http://ruedigergad.com/2012/01/28/hotplug-an-external-screen-to-your-laptop-on-linux/).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't get a udev event (according to the blog post). Is there another place I can look for a change? Maybe somewhere in the /proc hirearchy?